# Populate datalist via fetch

Tags: reactjs, html-datalist

Trying to populate a datalist with the parsed data from a fetch request, but the options are not appending. I'm pretty sure my problem is that the page hasn't rendered in time for the element to be found, but unsure how to go about fixing this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
        }).then(function (json) {
            for (var i = 0; i< json.length; i++) {
                var option = "<option value="+json[i]+'" >'+json[i]+'</option>';
                dataList.appendChild(option);     
                console.log(option);           
            }

            console.log(document.getElementById("datalist")); //returns null


return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="fetchList" placeholder="Select one..."  list="datalist" />
            <datalist id="datalist"></datalist>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track. `fetch()` is asynchronous, so your console.log(...) will be executed before `fetch()` has received and processed the response.

however, you can do something like the following to return the list once data has been received:

```
return (
        ...
        { dataList.length > 0
          ? <datalist id="datalist">
              { dataList.map((option) => 
                 { option }
              ) }
            </datalist>
          : 'Receiving data...'
        }
    )
```

UPDATE: I'd probably append only the actual values to the array and propagate the list using

```
<option value={option.value}>{option.name}</option>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated it as you suggested here, however, the list is still not populating after it gets the data. Remains on "Receiving data...".

Comment: I figured it out. It was a separate problem with my page refresh I need to fix. Click on a different page and return to this one and the dropdowns are populated. Accepted! Thanks for your suggestion.